# My normal map is green ?

Tags: texture-baking

So I ran into a problem while baking my textures.
Everything baked fine except for my normal map.
I'm not transferring normals; I'm just baking into an atlas for multiple assets.
But somehow my UV map looks like this[image: So much green on the texture]

I'm baking 2 table models into one atlas. One bakes properly (the one in purple) and the other is just all green.

Any idea how I can fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Is your object scaled (a lot)?

Comment: Nope. Uniform scale of 1

Comment: make sure that the normals are not inverted and maybe incease the Extrusion a bit, if it still doesn't work please share the objects

Comment: Ok, so something just happened.
I created a new blend file and appended the collection that contained the models.
I ran the bake again, and it came out perfect.
This may be a workaround, but I still don't know why the bakes had problems with the other blend file.
Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: it's hard to guess without the blend file, please share the original file